# FireOS, prevent from sleep mode but allow ambient mode

Tags: android, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv, amazon-fire-os

I have a Media App which just playing some music on the TV. There is no Video Content at all.

On Google TV, the app is still playing, and after a time the ambient mode is starting. So there is no issue.

On FireTV it's different. Without any changes at the current code, the FireOS stops playing the app after 20 minutes and goes into sleep mode.

I know i can:

- disable the screensaver
- remove this timeout with adb commands

But nobody want this.

Another way to prevent this, is by adding the flag `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`.
But with adding `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` the device is always on until i clear the flag (after stoping the media e.g.). But the ambient mode is never starting. Thats exactly what the flag is made for, but in my case, i want the ambient mode, but not the sleep mode.

Is there a solution to prevent the FireOS from sleep mode, but allow the ambient mode?

Answer (score 0):

Set a [Partial Wake Lock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK)

In this doc it says the apps playing audio should set it
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/faq-general.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with the partial wake lock, but it doesn't help. The problem is, that the tv will be power off, and the music can't play without tv speakers. The FireTV Stick is playing the music, the MediaSession is working, but without tv speaker the music will "stop"

Comment: is the TV that is powering off but the connected Fire TV Stick is still on?

Comment: yes, its the powersafe mode :-( with `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` i can prevent the mode, but the user got no screensaver (his configured one)